# GRASS i.rotate function not appearing - any idea's why?

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, rotate

[image]

I want to look at rotating a layer using GRASS' i.rotate tool, but it is not showing in the toolbox. Am I looking in the wrong place?

*Update*

I have run the i.rotate tool in GRASS independently but it is not creating the new rotated layer.

I inputted the original file and specified the output name and the rotation amount. After running, the output layer is not created/nothing happens.

[image]

*Update No.2*

Command window screenshot attached below

[image]

**r.Info Filtered_Scan**

[image]

**g.region**

[image]

Comment: You are looking in the right place but it seems `i.rotate` is no longer part of `GRASS GIS`. Even GRASS does not have it, but I don't know why.

Answer (score 3):

THe `i.rotate` module is still quite available as a GRASS [addon](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass82/manuals/addons/i.rotate.html): . In general, addons are not immediately accessible in the QGIS processing toolbox. I suggest you run GRASS itself, independent of QGIS, then install the addon with `g.extension`, and give it a try. If you encounter any difficulties, post back, stating what you tried, and what result you got.

GRASS GIS is a full professional GIS on its own. No need for QGIS. But QGIS has incorporated most of the GRASS modules into the Processing Toolbox. You can install GRASS on its own, download [here](https://grass.osgeo.org/download/windows). And. depending on how you installed QGIS, it should also come with a complete installation of GRASS.

**EDIT 09/01/2023**

THe first thing you need to do is match the computational region to the raster you're working with. (This is FAQ #1 in GRASS. Many people get caught on this issue). In grass almost **all** raster modules honor the *computational region*, not the extent of the input raster. (This has many advantages in other modules)

Your Filtered_Scan raster is about 1 degree by 3 degrees, with resolution 0:00:07 degrees (7 arc seconds) whereas the computational region is set to the default resolution of 1 degree resolution from -180 to +180 and -90 to +90. To get the region setting correct, just run:

```
g.region rast=Filtered_Scan
```

THen retry the rotate module.

Comment: Hi Micha, thank you for your helpful reply. Unfortunately, I have fallen at the first hurdle. How do you go about running GRASS independently of GIS? I thought it was integrated into GIS.

Comment: Have a look at the edits to my answer above.

Comment: Hi Micha, I have run the i.rotate tool in GRASS but it is not creating the rotate output. I have updated my question above with a screenshot of the issue. Do you know why the rotate layer is not being created? Thank you.

Comment: It's hard to see the whole command and error output in the screenshot. Can you copy/paste then post here the **text** of the actual command that you are running and the full output?

Comment: Also please add the output of these commands:
`r.info Filtered_Scan`

and:
`g.region -ap`

Comment: Hi Micha, I am using the GUI to run the i.rotate command. I have edited my question with the command window included in the screenshot. Below is the output message 

"(Mon Jan  9 11:56:21 2023)                                                      
i.rotate input=Filtered_Scan@PERMANENT output=Rotated_scan angle=35             
(Mon Jan  9 11:56:22 2023) Command finished (1 sec)"

Comment: r.info Filtered_Scan output is too long to post here, so I have attached the output as a screenshot in my question. Thank you for your continued help - it is much appreciated.

Comment: g.region output:

(Mon Jan  9 12:18:05 2023)                                                      
g.region -p                                                                     
projection: 3 (Latitude-Longitude)
zone:       0
datum:      wgs84
ellipsoid:  wgs84
north:      90N
south:      90S
west:       180W
east:       180E
nsres:      1
ewres:      1
rows:       180
cols:       360
cells:      64800
(Mon Jan  9 12:18:06 2023) Command finished (0 sec)

Comment: Please see edits to the answer above

Comment: Hi Micha, I will give this a go. Thank you very much for your help - much appreciated.